# How to apply a function over multiple excel sheets in R?

Tags: r, excel, function

I have an `excel` with two `sheets` and I want to apply a `function` I created to both `sheets`. What I have done is to make those sheets a `list` of `data frames`. I have created my `function` but it seems it doesn't work. I have followed this [tutorial](https://www.reed.edu/data-at-reed/resources/R/excel.html). Here is a reproducible example.

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(1416182400, 1416873600, 1417564800, 
1418256000, 1418947200, 1419638400, 1420070400, 1420761600, 1421452800, 
1422144000, 1422835200, 1423526400, 1424217600, 1424908800, 1425600000, 
1426291200, 1426982400, 1427673600, 1428364800, 1429056000, 1429747200, 
1430438400, 1431129600, 1431820800, 1432512000, 1433203200, 1433894400, 
1434585600, 1435276800, 1435968000, 1436659200), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), DOY = c("321", "329", "337", "345", 
"353", "361", "001", "009", "017", "025", "033", "041", "049", 
"057", "065", "073", "081", "089", "097", "105", "113", "121", 
"129", "137", "145", "153", "161", "169", "177", "185", "193"
), `1556_7S_15D` = c("4", "2", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "3", 
"3", "4", "NA", "NA", "4", "4", "4", "4", "3", "4", "4", "4", 
"4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4"), `2216_7S_15D` = c("3", 
"3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "2", "3", "NA", "3", "NA", "NA", "3", 
"NA", "NA", "1", "NA", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", 
"3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3"), `3220_7S_15D` = c("6", "1", "6", 
"6", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", "2", "5", "6", "6", "6", "6", 
"NA", "6", "6", "6", "NA", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", 
"6", "6", "6"), `3343_7S_15D` = c("4", "NA", "4", "4", "4", "4", 
"4", "4", "2", "4", "NA", "NA", "4", "4", "4", "2", "NA", "4", 
"4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4"
), `4168_7S_15D` = c("2", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "NA", "4", 
"NA", "4", "NA", "NA", "4", "4", "4", "4", "NA", "4", "4", "4", 
"NA", "4", "3", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4"), `4303_7S_15D` = c("4", 
"4", "4", "NA", "4", "4", "4", "4", "NA", "4", "NA", "4", "4", 
"4", "NA", "NA", "NA", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", 
"4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4"), `4304_7S_15D` = c("4", "4", "4", 
"NA", "4", "4", "4", "4", "NA", "4", "NA", "4", "4", "4", "NA", 
"NA", "NA", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", 
"4", "4", "4", "4"), `4307_7S_15D` = c("3", "2", "3", "NA", "3", 
"3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "NA", "3", "3", "NA", "3", "3", 
"3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", 
"3"), `4556_7S_15D` = c("3", "NA", "3", "3", "NA", "3", "3", 
"3", "NA", "3", "3", "2", "3", "3", "NA", "NA", "3", "3", "3", 
"3", "2", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3"), 
    `4573_7S_15D` = c("4", "NA", "4", "4", "NA", "4", "4", "4", 
    "4", "4", "NA", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", 
    "2", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4"), DOY_SEQ = c(26, 
    27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
    13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25)), row.names = c(NA, 
-31L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

The code I have used so far is:

```
df = read_excel("test.xlsx")
colnames(df)

path <- "test.xlsx"

#get the sheet names
path %>%
  excel_sheets()

#transform the sheets into a list of data frames
df <- path %>%
  excel_sheets() %>%
  set_names() %>%
  map(read_excel,
      path = path)

str(df)

cleaner <- function(df){
  # drop 1st rows of each sheet
  df <- subset(df, select = -c(Date))
  # transform all cells from char to num 
  df[] <- lapply(df, as.numeric)
  # interpolation using splines
  df[] <- lapply(df, zoo::na.spline)
  # return cleaned df      
  return(df)
}
str(df)
```

Comment: If `df` has list of dataframes do `lapply(df, cleaner)`.

Comment: Thank for the fast reply. Do you mean to insert your code after the `function`?

Comment: Yes, did you try that?

Comment: I did and still no result. For example, the type of the `cells` are still `character` values.

Comment: `df[] <- lapply(df, cleaner)`

Comment: Yes, now it works! Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can also use

```
 library(purrr)
 map_dfr(df, cleaner)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `lapply` to loop over the list of dataframes and apply `cleaner` function to each dataframe.

```
df[] <- lapply(df, cleaner)
```

Similarly, using `purrr::map`

```
df[] <- purrr::map(df, cleaner)
```