# Adding sheet names to dataframe output

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I have excel file with multiple sheet which are labelled based on the comparison I have made.

Here is the code which i have used from this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61115340/how-to-apply-a-function-over-multiple-excel-sheets-in-r)

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df = read_excel("FAB_all_DOWN.xlsx")
colnames(df)

path <- "FAB_all_DOWN.xlsx"

#get the sheet names
path %>%
  excel_sheets()

#transform the sheets into a list of data frames
df <- path %>%
  excel_sheets() %>%
  set_names() %>%
  map(read_excel,
      path = path)




filter_qval = function(df,q_value_rev){
  filter_df = df[df$q_value_rev < 0.05,]
  return(filter_df)
}
  

a <- map_dfr(df, filter_qval)

a <- filter_by_q_value(df)
dim(a)
```

Here the output of the of the sheetname as such

```
path %>%
+   excel_sheets()
 [1] "M0_vs_M1" "M0_vs_M2" "M0_vs_M3" "M0_vs_M4" "M0_vs_M5" "M1_vs_M2" "M1_vs_M3" "M1_vs_M4" "M1_vs_M5" "M2_vs_M3"
[11] "M2_vs_M4" "M2_vs_M5" "M3_vs_M4" "M3_vs_M5" "M4_vs_M5"
```

My function to filter q_value is as such

```
filter_qval = function(df,q_value_rev){
  filter_df = df[df$q_value_rev < 0.05,]
  return(filter_df)
}
```

Next I did this

```
a <- map_dfr(df, filter_qval)
```

The output of a looks something like this

```
GroupID  Category                Term       Description  LogP `Log(q-value)` q_value_rev InTerm_InList Genes Symbols
  <chr>    <chr>                   <chr>      <chr>       <dbl>          <dbl>       <dbl> <chr>         <chr> <chr>  
1 1_Member GO Biological Processes GO:0042742 defense re… -24.4          -20.1    8.33e-21 40/351        306,… ANXA3,…
2 1_Member GO Biological Processes GO:0009617 response t… -22.8          -18.8    1.76e-19 53/732        306,… ANXA3,…
3 1_Member GO Biological Processes GO:0006959 humoral im… -19.1          -15.3    5.48e-16 32/291        566,… AZU1,C…
4 1_Member GO Biological Processes GO:0006956 complement… -18.0          -14.2    5.85e-15 22/122        712,… C1QA,C…
5 1_Member GO Biological Processes GO:0006958 complement… -15.6          -12.0    1.04e-12 19/106        712,… C1QA,C…
6 1_Member GO Biological Processes GO:0002455 humoral im… -15.2          -11.7    1.83e-12 19/110        712,… C1QA,C…
```

In this output I wanted to add another column which will show the sheetname label which would help me to check from which sheet the rows are coming from.

Any suggestion or help would be really helpful.

Comment: `map_dfr` has an `.id` argument, i.e. try `map_dfr(df, filter_qval, .id = "sheet")` to add a column `"sheet"` with the sheet names aka the names of your df list.

Comment: thank you very much it works it was so simple i couldn't think